# How to fix 'StdinNotImplementedError' in python interactive in Visual Studio Code

Tags: input, visual-studio-code, python-interactive

I'm using Visual Studio Code (1.34.0) and Python extension by microsoft for python coding. I tried using the input() function in the Python Interactive window and got an error 'StdinNotImplementedError'.

### Error

> StdinNotImplementedError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 input()
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py in > >  raw_input(self, prompt)
>       687         if not self._allow_stdin:
>       688             raise StdinNotImplementedError(
>   --> 689                 "raw_input was called, but this frontend does not > > support input requests."
>       690             )
>      691         return self._input_request(str(prompt),
>
> StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not >  support input requests..

### Software

Windows 10
Visual Studio Code (1.34.0)
Python extension by microsoft 
Python 3.6.0
Anaconda 4.3.0
Jupyter Notebook Version: (4, 3, 1)

How can I fix this error? Maybe I should change some settings?